# Is it possible for some one in Afghanistan to get a tweet from a person in the USA as an SMS in their Afghan cell phone? How?

Tags: twitter, sms, tweet

I need to be able to update people in Afghanistan with SMS messages to their cell phones. I thought the best way to do this was to get them all to sign-up for twitter and then subscribe to my tweets and make it so those tweets go to their cell phones.

Do you think this plan makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wouldn't be possible as Afghanistan is not in the Country list on Twitter.  You need to register all of these details in order to receive Tweets.
[image]

Comment: http://www.tweetsms.com/pricing

Comment: I think my idea is possible. I found this service called Tweet SMS. For about 10 cents an SMS you can send and get Tweets from a cell phone not hooked to the web. This service takes advantage of the Tweeter API. If anyone has used this service, I would appreciate your review. Cheers.

Comment: Eww... JPEG screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think my idea is possible.

I found this service called [Tweet SMS.](http://www.tweetsms.com/pricing)

For about 10 cents an SMS you can send and get Tweets from a cell phone not hooked to the web. This service takes advantage of the Tweeter API.

If anyone has used this service, I would appreciate your review. Cheers